# Modelling constraint

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, modeling, integer-programming

**I have the following problem statement:**

A company is considering to hire more operators. Starting with four machine operators
in May, the company wants to investigate if it pays off to hire more. Each operator has a
monthly cost of $3000. Due to local union agreements, once a person is hired, this
person cannot be sacked (at least not in this 4 month period), hence once hired in
one month, that person has to stay for the entire time-period.

How would one model this as a constraint?

Comment: The problem description is obviously incomplete. Probably there is some data on the benefits of hiring someone.

Comment: I have added the full problem

Comment: This is not a good way to ask a question. Please read https://or.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I know. The issue is just that the problem description is quite extensive so it is difficult to formulate it with just the problem statement itself.

Comment: Also possibly relevant: https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/229/38

Answer (score 3):

Without the entire problem description it is hard to provide a complete answer, but you will probably need a variable $x_t \in \mathbb{N}$ for the number of operators hired at time period $t$.

With these variables, and taking into account the fact that once an operator is hired, he is hired for the entire time period, the extra cost at a given time $t$ equals  $\\\$ 3000$ times the number of operators hired up to time $t$, that is:
$$
3000 \sum_{i,i\le t} x_i
$$
So you want to minimize this term over the entire time span:
$$
3000\sum_t\sum_{i,i\le t} x_i
$$